# Making @username clickable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace, mootools

Below code works on the Mootools library, I would like it to work on jQuery if possible, I so far had no luck.

HTML

```
<p id="test">@user has an email address of user@email.com. See! the regexp works @people!</p>
```

MooTools

```
$('test').set('html', $('test').get('html').replace(/\B\@([\w\-]+)/gim, function(match, name){
    return '<a href="http://twitter.com/users/' + name + '">' + match + '</a>';
}));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2TQsx/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#test').html($('#test').html().replace(/\B\@([\w\-]+)/gim, function(match, name){
    return '<a href="http://twitter.com/users/' + name + '">' + match + '</a>';
}));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2TQsx/6/)

Comment: Should help to note that the selector will work on element types unless prepended with a `#` (for id) or `.` (for class).

Comment: Sorry Rory, I celebrated too early. I have a look at this, its only repeating the first paragraph instead of all. http://jsfiddle.net/hnAQX/

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/2TQsx/9/) with this a bit for you:

```
$('#test').html($('#test').html().replace(/\B\@([\w\-]+)/gim, function(match, name){
    return '<a href="http://twitter.com/users/' + name + '">' + match + '</a>';
}));​
```

The key differences are:

- finding `test` by id by prefixing the selector with `#`
- using `element.html()` method to get and set html, instead of `get` and `set`

Answer (score 0):

A mootools native solution for tweets - i know you want to go the jquery route but for reference.

```
String.implement({
    linkify: function(){
        // courtesy of Jeremy Parrish (rrish.org)
        return String(this).replace(/(https?:\/\/[\w\-:;?&=+.%#\/]+)/gi, '<a href="$1">$1</a>')
            .replace(/(^|\W)@(\w+)/g, '$1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2">@$2</a>')
            .replace(/(^|\W)#(\w+)/g, '$1#<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$2">$2</a>');
    }
});


var tests = [
    "@user has an email address of user@email.com. See! the regexp works @people!",
    "@d_mitar likes #mootools a fair bit. http://foo.com#bar"
];



// on proto
tests.each(function(el) {
    new Element("div", {
        html: el.linkify()
    }).inject(document.body);

});

// on host object
tests.each(function(el) {
    new Element("div", {
        html: String.linkify(el)
    }).inject(document.body);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/fG4KF/

this also deals with converting hash tags and URLs